# Is IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback really a sink?

Tags: streaming, ms-media-foundation

I have started writing some streaming code which connects a Windows Media Foundation session to the live555 streaming library. So far, I have started writing a `IMFMediaSink` and my own `IMFStreamSink`. However, the code got quickly quite complex.

I was wondering whether I could also use `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` as it would just receive the samples which I would forward to live555.

Before refactoring the code, I wonder whether the MF sink is really a sink - I remember that in DirectShow, the sample grabber could not be used without another sink as it was a transform. Can I build a topology that receives samples, passes them through a DMO, an encoder and finally to the sink without any other nodes?

Furthermore, I wonder what the disadvantages of such an approach would be (provided it would work)? The obvious one I see is that `IMFMediaSink` supports multiple streams and hence could coordinate audio and video. However, as live555 does that purely via timestamps, I have no real benefit from it. Are there any other disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Grabber works pretty much the same way as DirectShow Sample Grabber: you can insert a pipeline object with additional simplified outer interface so that you obtain ability to "export" payload data from the pipeline as it is streamed. You provide a callback interface to get called as new data is available. This is true for both sample grabbers.

DirectShow SG is more flexible in terms that it is a transform and you can add it anywhere in the topology. MF SG is an output node only. MF SG offers more callback methods (`IMFClockStateSink` methods). DirectShow SG is a really simple filter [a variant of which is] available in source code as SDK sample.

DirectShow SG was not originally the API core, but it was very popular among developers. I suppose its popularity was the primary reason a similar component was developed for MF: they kept the naming, the concept - everything. In the same time Microsoft retired DirectShow SG and excluded it from most recent OS versions even though it is clear that the API is still being used. Go figure the logic.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, but let me rephrase my question: I do not understand how the MF SG would work being an output node, because as I understand, the output node triggers the generation of samples in the upstream node by raising `MEStreamSinkRequestSample`. However, `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` is not an `IMFMediaEventGenerator` like `IMFStreamSink`. I have a (somehow) working version based on `IMFMediaSink` and `IMFStreamSink`, and it does not get any sample without this event ...

Comment: You don't plug `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` right there into pipeline. The sample grabber itself implements what it takes to be a part of topology, so it consumes the data on its own letting you not worry too much about the details. And additionally, it accepts the callback interface to notify you on data. They did design SG as a media sink in MF, hence it acts as an output node. Also, if you only want to read from MF source, I would look at source reader instead. Source reader allows automatic decoders as well (if needed) and let's you pull data synchronously and asynchronously.

Comment: OK ... So `MFCreateSampleGrabberSinkActivate` creates a node for me, which implements the `IMFMediaSink`, pulls the data and forwards it to the `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` I pass to `MFCreateSampleGrabberSinkActivate`? I didn't get the idea from the documentation ...

Comment: I think the idea od sample grabber sink can be described as simple as a converter from MF sink and output node to calls on application provided `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` interface. As simple as this. Just like with DirectShow, for those not wanting to get into details, this offers reducing complexity to as small thing as implementation of callback interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can call MFCreateSampleGrabberSinkActivate function for creating of activate MF object. This function needs MediaType - it must be type of encoding which is needed in your code. You can find example code for capturing video from web camera via MF on site [videoinput](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an). It includes source code and allows grab frames in RGB24, RGB32, AYUV formats. If you set H264 format then MF finds the suitable encoder for it and SampleGrabberSink callback with data of H264 format, but you must set the correct MediaType.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code - I will have a look at it and let you know whether it answers my question.